# Select_Tag only selecting the first value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I'm having trouble with the rails select tag. In both cases the select_tag is passing the first item in the array no matter what was selected.

The user_address array comes from one of my models and the delivery plans only have the two options below. I've been reading documentation, but I always get an error whenever I try to add a `selected => 'plan'` for example.

Can someone advise on the proper syntax

```
  <<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargeForm' do %>

                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail', current_user.email %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'amount', final_charge %>
                        <%= text_field_tag 'tax', tax_amount %>
                         <b><%= label_tag 'Select a shipping address:' %></b>
                            <%= select_tag 'address_id', options_for_select(user_address.collect{ |address| [address.full_street_address, address.id]},) %>
                        <b><%= label_tag 'Select a delivery plan:' %></b>&nbsp;
                            <%= select_tag 'plan',["One Time Order","Weekly Subscription"] %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'chickenVegetables_quantity', chickenVegetables_quantity %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'chickenRice_quantity', chickenRice_quantity %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'beefCouscous_quantity', beefCouscous_quantity %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'beefVegetables_quantity', beefVegetables_quantity %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id %>


                        <button id="btn-buy1" type="button" class="button i-submit">
                            Checkout
                        </button>
                        <script>
                        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                            key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
                            email: '<%=current_user.email%>',
                            token: function(token, arg) {
                                document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                                document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                                document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
                            }
                        });
                        document.getElementById('btn-buy1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                            handler.open({
                                name: 'Name',
                                description: 'Purchase',
                                amount:  document.getElementById("amount").value
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                        })
                        </script>
                        <% end %>
```

Charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create


if params[:plan] == 'One Time Order'
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )
else
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :card  => params[:stripeToken],
    :plan => "meal_subscription",
    :quantity => params[:chickenVegetables_quantity]
  )
end


  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => params[:amount],
    :description => 'PetPlate customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

   purchase = Purchase.create(email: params[:stripeEmail], card: params[:stripeToken], 
    amount: params[:amount], description: charge.description, currency: charge.currency,
    customer_id: customer.id, chickenVegetables_quantity: params[:chickenVegetables_quantity], chickenRice_quantity: params[:chickenRice_quantity], 
    beefCouscous_quantity: params[:beefCouscous_quantity],beefVegetables_quantity: params[:beefVegetables_quantity],user_id: params[:user_id], tax: params[:tax],
    address: params[:address], apt_no: params[:apt_no], city: params[:city], state: params[:state], zip_code: params[:zip_code], phone_number: params[:phone_number], 
    restaurant_id: params[:restaurant_id], address_id: params[:address_id], plan: params[:plan])

redirect_to purchase

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

if you go through the documentation of `options_for_select` you will find that if you need to select a an option by default you will have to pass it as a 2nd parameter to `options_for_select`

So in your case it would be something like this

```
<%= select_tag 'address_id', options_for_select([user_address.collect{ |address| [address.full_street_address, address.id]}],@selected_address.id) %> # if user address to be selected is @selected_address
<%= select_tag 'plan',options_for_select(["One Time Order","Weekly Subscription"],"Weekly Subscription")%> # to select 2nd option
```

Comment: It works for the subscription, but I get a ''undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass' error ont he @selected_address.id

Comment: @selected_address need to be the object , I guess in your case it should be object of `UserAddress` I am guessing this model on the base of convention.

Comment: Just checked again and for the 'plan' it now only passes the second option. How do I just pass what the user selected?

Comment: Passing or Selecting ?

Comment: Passing. I want the user to select and option and for that to pass into the form

Comment: can you paste the whole partial/view in your question and that specific controller action where you want to pass the params ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88271/discussion-between-webbr88-and-kinaan-khan-sherwani).